# Test coverage is not covering any suit

Tags: angular, npm, jasmine, karma-runner

I am working on angular 2 project and writing test cases for services. Before the test cases was running perfectly but now i am getting some no provider error like (No provider for AppService!). After adding aforesaid provider when i am checking for coverage, test cases are not getting covered.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your all services @Injectable() decoratore with providedIn: 'root' option, so you won't have to import the service and add in providers array.

```
 @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })
```

Comment: When i am trying to inject providedIn: root, there is a ts error that expected 0 arguments but got 1.

Comment: What is the angular version you are using?

Comment: I am using angular version 2.4.8

Comment: Ohh ok.. Provide in root work in angular 4.3+. Just import the service in test file and add it in providers array like we do in app.module file.